# What's the song that plays when Sasuke and Kakashi arrive at round 3 of the Chunin Exams?

Tags: naruto, music

What's the song that plays when Sasuke and Kakashi arrive at round 3 of the Chunin Exams (when they replay it in *Shippuden* episode 258, at 19:18)  I don't think this is the only time it plays but it's the first example I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds somewhat similar to *Sarutobi*, from Naruto OST III, track 12.

However, there are some differences, so it's not the exact same track. The song in that episode doesn't seem to be in any of the officially released soundtracks. There are some unofficial versions online though, usually titled *Sarutobi Remix* or *Surprise Attack*. For example, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoZQl0AAn9U).